# Can a store app run on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

I don't know is it possible or not to use a windows store app on to to work on windows 7 machine ?
There is a game app that needs to be transferred in to windows 7 from a windows 8.1 machine

Comment: No. Store Apps are using a Runtime which is not a part in Windows 7.

Comment: Perhaps you could run a Windows 8+ VM or boot to a Windows 8+ VHD on an otherwise Windows 7 box. Otherwise you'd need to backport the game app to Win32.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do Windows 8 Metro Apps run in Windows 7 or XP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852753/do-windows-8-metro-apps-run-in-windows-7-or-xp)

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to install Windows Runtime on Windows 7. 
Windows Runtime is available only starting from Windows 8.